# Solve $\Big[\frac{y+\sin x.\cos^2(xy)}{\cos^2(xy)}\Big]dx+\Big[\frac{x}{\cos^2(xy)}+\sin y\Big]dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solution of $$\Big[\frac{y+\sin x.\cos^2(xy)}{\cos^2(xy)}\Big]dx+\Big[\frac{x}{\cos^2(xy)}+\sin y\Big]dy=0$$
>   is

$$
\frac{y}{\cos^2(xy)}+\sin x+\Big[\frac{x}{\cos^2(xy)}+\sin y\Big]\frac{dy}
{dx}=0\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y+\sin x.\cos^2(xy)}{x+\sin y.\cos^2(xy)}=-\frac{\dfrac{y}{\cos^2(xy)}+\sin x}{\dfrac{x}{\cos^2(xy)}+\sin y}\\
$$

Could anyone help me with a hint on how to approach this differential equation in the most general way ?

I am not looking for any shortcuts which are not obvious when I look t the given equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding as 
$$\frac {y\cdot{dx} + x\cdot{dy}}{cos^2(xy)} + sin(x){dx}+ sin(y){dy}=0$$
Notice that $y\cdot{dx} + x\cdot{dy}= {d(xy)}$ 
Hence the answer obtained by simply integrating on both sides is $$\boxed{tan(xy) = cos(x) + cos (y) + C}$$

Comment: Have you, by any chance, given or plan to take JEE?

Comment: I just gave it in January, what about u?

Comment: 99.77, but flunked the integrals. PS : Dear mods, i dont know how to start chats

Comment: Actually i was 99.67

Answer (score 1):

$$\Big[\frac{y+\sin x.\cos^2(xy)}{\cos^2(xy)}\Big]dx+\Big[\frac{x}{\cos^2(xy)}+\sin y\Big]dy=0$$
$$\frac{ydx+xdy}{\cos^2(xy)}+\sin (x) dx+\sin ydy=0$$
$$\frac{d(xy)}{\cos^2(xy)}-d(\cos (x))-d(\cos(y))=0$$
$$d({\tan(xy)})-d(\cos (x))-d(\cos(y))=0$$
Integrate:
$$\tan(xy)-\cos (x)-\cos(y)=K$$